# Sell different products in bunch of fixed quantity

Tags: magento-1, bundled-product

I would like to sell a set of products as follows:

A set of 20 lipsticks where 10 color options are available:

The customer can purchase any combination of colors with any qty, but a total qty of 20.

#### For example

- 5 Red, 4 Yellow, 7 pink, 4 green
- 10 Red, 3 Yellow, 3 pink, 4 green
- 3 Red, 2 Yellow, 9 pink, 6 purple
- 15 Red, 5 Blue
- 2 Red, 2 Blue, 2 Yellow, 2 pink, 2 purple, 6 brown, 4 gold

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Check for Item Sku and final quantity of the the cart

Comment: most probably you need to create custom product type for this.

Comment: Please take your time to accept an answer if it helped you. http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can see how to achieve this without custom product types is using a bundle product with 20 options, where each option has a fixed qty of 1 and all colors as possible selection (the colored lipsticks are of course simple products).

This means, the shop frontend will show 20 dropdowns and the customer has to select each single item.

If you want a different frontend, like qty inputs for each color with validation, or maybe sliders, I would still suggest this approach. You can hide the original dropdowns, create the interface as you like it and use JavaScript to set the correct values in the hidden dropdowns.

Answer (score -1):

Easy to achieve with Magento:

Example as: 5 Red, 4 Yellow, 7 pink, 4 green

1. Create one Group product as "Lipstick"
2. Create 4 simple products for Red, Yellow, Pink, Green
3. Open Group product & inside tab **Associated Products** add these 4 simple product.
4. Also set default quantity as : 5 Red, 4 Yellow, 7 pink, 4 green
5. That's it.

Comment: This solution is missing the "20 items total" constraint.

Comment: Did you missed the point no. 4 ?

Comment: No. But the user can change default qtys to whatever they want. OP wants them to always sum up to 20.

Comment: Then you still have two options: Use some jquery OR use Bundled instead Group